# Emacs doesn't recognize if file is under version control

Tags: vc, vc-mode

I noticed I never see in the mode line in which VCS branch I'm currently in, when I open a file in Emacs.

So I tried it with an empty Emacs, created a folder in Eshell, called `~/foo`
, and initialized Git with `git init` inside `~/foo`. 
Then I have Emacs created a buffer inside `~/foo` with `M-x find-file` `bar.txt`. I saved the file, and in Eshell I did `[user ~/foo] git add bar.txt`.

But I don't see any VCS-related in the mode line.
When I run <kbd>C-x v =</kbd> Emacs tells me that `bar.txt` is not under version control. And the same story when I revert the buffer.

When I do the following <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(eval (executable-find "git")`, it pointed to `/usr/bin/git` which is correct.

`Auto-revert-mode`didn't help it. What else can I do in order to figure out how this issue is caused? Git in terminal tells me that `bar.txt` is recognized and tracked by Git.

Comment: `M-:` is a command to *evaluate* an expression, so there's no need to use `eval` within it.

Comment: Have you tried with `emacs -Q`?

Answer (score 2):

The VC packages uses caching, and in many places assumes that the user interacts with VCS systems (e.g. Git) through it.

To register a new file in a Git repository, press `C-x v v`, you don't need to use Eshell for that.

If you've changed a buffer's status using something else than VC commands, though, you can visit the file again to refresh the status information. The easiest way to do that, IMO, is `M-x revert-buffer`.

Also make sure that `vc-handled-backends` includes `Git`, which it does by default.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried `C-x v v` and I got only the message "Use VC backend:" with an empty list in helm-mode-vc-next-action". Still no master or any branch in mode line.

Comment: Could you try running Emacs with -Q and then repeating the procedure again?  I'm wondering if some other package or setting you've got enabled is causing the problem.

Comment: Helm is an obvious culprit, going by `helm-mode-vc-next-action` being present in the scenario.

Comment: I included `(setq vc-handled-backends "Git")` and evaluated it. But when I call `C-x v v`, I got the error  `Wrong type argument: symbolp, 71` and there is no command `helm-mode-vc-next-action` in `M-x`. What would you suggest?

Comment: @ReneFroger That should be `(setq vc-handled-backends '(Git))`

Comment: Thanks npostavs, that changed something. After `C-x v v`, I got only the message `fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'` in `vc-diff` buffer.

Comment: @ReneFroger That happens. VC doesn't know how to diff against a branch that contains zero revisions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `C-x C-v` (find-alternate-file) to reload bar.txt.  You should then see "Git@master" in the mode line.

Comment: It didn't help, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `vc-git-program` value.  I just hit this issue and found that I had customised it (well actually `vc-hg-program` in my case) and the program was missing from the specified location.